# PHP or Perl: Is it possible to pass "value" to a textbox without the "name" attribute?

Tags: php, perl

Good day.
I would like to ask something, which might not even be possible, but I will ask it anyway, who knows. :-)

Currently, I have a Perl/PHP script that does login and a little bit of webscraping.
It was working perfectly fine for the past 2 years. Then one day, it stopped. I then realized that the login elements (name and password textboxes) have changed names! And they are doing this on an almost monthly basis, randomly.

So I am wondering if it possible to pass value to a textbox without a name. Below is my current Perl code. You can notice the field names "txtUsername" and "txtPassword". They are the ones that are now changing at a regular basis.

```
    $submitform->submit_form(
    form_number => 1,
    fields    => {
        'txtUsername' => $username,
        'txtPassword' => $password,
    },
);
```

Thanks in advance for the help guys!

Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I am wondering if it possible to pass value to a textbox without a
>   name.

No, you must provide the names. To solve the problem:

1. Fetch the page with form
2. Parse it, getting the inputs names
3. Submit the form with appropriate names

Comment: thanks for your response user4035... :-) may I ask though if do you have samples or links for items (1) and (2)?

Comment: @RobEarthSoftworks Use WWW::Mechanize to fetch the data and HTML::TreeBuilder to parse the HTML. They have pretty good documentation.

Comment: hmmm. thanks user4035! yeah, i think that's a great solution. I am actually using mechanize to parse some info in some pages for this particular script. Did not realize that until you mentioned it, that I can actually use it in this case! Thanks! +1 for you... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Did they change names or positions as they appear? And no,text boxes need names and values. Names usually match the database columns and values are what the user enters into the database. 
Alphabetically, it would be interesting to know which comes first.

Comment: hi Edwinner. Nope, they did not change positions. only their names. textboxes were given a seemingly random names e.g. "ered4dew". yep, i agree that the names are "usually" based from the database column or for what info they are for, but this can actually be overridden manually or automated, which I believe what is happening in this case: randomly generated.